# Coming up with an Algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, equation, createjs

I have a circle in my canvas. The mouse position is calculated in relation to the canvas. I want the circle to move when the mouse is at <=100px distance from it. The minimum distance to start moving is 100px, at 0.5px/tick. It goes up to 2px/tick at 20px distance.

## Basically, the closer the mouse is to the circle, the faster the circle should move.

What I have so far moves the circle when distance is less or equal to 100 -- (I'm using easeljs library)

```
function handleTick() {
    distance = calculateDistance(circle, mX, mY);
    if (distance<=100) {
        circle.x += 0.3;
    
    stage.update();
    }
}
```

What I want

```
function handleTick() {
    distance = calculateDistance(circle, mX, mY);
    if (distance<=100) {
        circleSpeed = // equation that takes distance and outputs velocity px/tick.
        circle.x += circleSpeed;
    
    stage.update();
    }
}
```

So I thought this was a mathmatical problem and posted it on math exchange, but so far no answers. I tried googling several topics like: "how to come up with an equation for a relation" since I have the domain (100, 20) and the range (0.5, 2). What function can relate them?

Thing is I'm bad at math, and these numbers might not even have a relation - I'm not sure what I'm looking for here.

Should I write a random algorithm "`circleSpeed = 2x + 5x;`" and hope it does what I want? Or is it possible to do as I did - "I want these to be the minimum and maximum values, now I need to come up with an equation for it"?

A pointer in the right direction would be great because so far I'm shooting in the dark.

Comment: You are going to change the speed by 1.5px over a distance of 80px -> a change of 0.01875 px in speed per pixel.

Comment: you forgot one important piece of information: what should be the relation-ship between speed and distance? linear, logarithmic, ...

Comment: @Paul you are going to confuse OP even more with terms like this :p

Comment: @RishavKundu i know, though the problem is that OP is asking for a function without specifying exact behaviour of the function. So far we only know it should be continously falling

Comment: This is not about maths, or even about programming. It's about you deciding what you want the relationship between speed and distance to be. Since it's arbitrary, only you can define it. When you have done that you'll probably find that programming it is simple.

Comment: @Paul let’s just provide him a simple linear relationship, eh?

Comment: @Rishav Kundu that was so simple x) haha 1.5px/80.@Paul ye with those terms I won't get there. I mean linear is steady-growth I get it but aside from that one I have no idea what logarithmic would be. I guess I'll pay more attention to math class next year >.<

Comment: @Harlequin not really :p see my answer

Comment: @Harlequin check out my edited answer. I’d made a mistake lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want `circleSpeed` to be a function of `distance`, such that

- `circleSpeed` is `0.5` when `distance` is `100`.
- `circleSpeed` is `2` when `distance` is `20`.

There are infinity functions which fulfill that, so I will assume linearity.

The equation of the line with slope `m` and which contains the point `(x₀,y₀)` is

```
y = m (x-x₀) + y₀
```

But in this case you have two points, `(x₁,y₁)` and `(x₂,y₂)`, so you can calculate the slope with

```
    y₂ - y₁
m = ───────
    x₂ - x₁
```

So the equation of the line is

```
    y₂ - y₁
y = ─────── (x - x₁) + y₁
    x₂ - x₁
```

With your data,

```
    0.5 - 2 
y = ──────── (x - 20) + 2 = -0.01875 x + 2.375
    100 - 20
```

Therefore,

```js
circleSpeed = -0.01875 * distance + 2.375
```

Comment: And you make me @RishavKundu where does that leave me? xD

Comment: @Oriol 'a' is what in that equation? 'b' is where the line crosses the 'y' axis. 'b' is 'y1' in your solution, why? where did the 2.375 came from? =P

Comment: @Harlequin I have unified the notations. `(xᵢ,yᵢ)` are points that belong to the line, that is, when `x=xᵢ`, then `y=yᵢ`. `2.375` comes from `(.5-2)/(100-20)*(-20)+2`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want a linear relation between the distance and speed?

If so, you could do something like `circleSpeed = (2.5 - 0.5(distance/20))`.
That would, however set the speed linearly from 0 to 2.5 on the range (100 to 0), but by using another if like this `if (distance < 20) circleSpeed = 2` you would limit the speed to 2.0 at 20 range.

It's not 100% accurate to what you asked for, but pretty close and it should look ok I guess. It could possibly also be tweaked to get closer.

However if you want to make the circle move away from the mouse, you also need to do something to calculate the correct direction of movement as well, and your problem gets a tiny bit more complex as you need to calculate `speed_x` and `speed_y`

Comment: Yes I was going to do that after the speed thingy. Thanks, still reading through

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple snippet to animate the speed *linearly*, what that means is that is the acceleration of the circle will be constant.

```
if distance > 100:
    print 0
elseif distance < 20:
    print 2
else:
    print  2 - (distance -20 ) * 0.01875
```

Yet other relationships are possible, (other easings you might call them) but they will be more complicated, hehe.

**EDIT**: Whoops, I’d made a mistake.